# Difficulties arranging elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Im struggling with some arraning of html elements in my reactjs project. Im new to all the webdevelopment and also to css and i have absolutly no idea how to resolve it in a responsive way. Im trying to solve the following placement of elemtns within my app: 
[Link to what i try to archieve](https://ibb.co/WG7ZmQJ)
Here i show you what i actually have in react-jsx:

```
<img className="img" src={this.props.img_1} alt="DummyPicture" />
      <span className="personName">{this.props.name_1}</span>
      <span className="personAge">({this.props.age_1})</span>
      <span className="personMatching">
        {this.props.matching_1}% gemeinsame Interessen
      </span>

<img className="img" src={this.props.img_2} alt="DummyPicture" />
    <span className="personName">
      {this.props.name_2} ({this.props.age_2})
     </span>
     <span className="personMatching">
       {this.props.matching_2}% gemeinsame Interessen
     </span>
```

And here my css:

```
.personName {
  width: 30%;
   float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
   }

.personAge {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
 }
.personMatching {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
 }

.img {
  width: 48pt;
  height: 48pt;
  float: left;

  margin-left: 5%;
 }
```

I also tried it with thinks like flex-box or display:inline but I think I just have a lack of knowledge about it. Hope someone of you can help me out here.

Comment: I would suggest reading up on how to use flex-box. [Flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) is a good website to learn how to use it in a playful manner.

Comment: As per [Prerequsites](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#prerequisites) in their *basic* tutorial, it is assumed you are familiar with HTML and JavaScript. You can't use React without knowing HTML and JavaScript. And you can't really use any of the two without CSS. Most of what JavaScript does regarding DOM is change CSS (and HTML) on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice today is to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

As you see in the example below, flex will align items for you.

```css
.person {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.age {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.matching, .name {
  margin: 5px 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 48pt;
  height: 48pt;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">
  <img class="img" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/81.jpg" alt="DummyPicture" />
  <div class="info">
    <p class="name">Caroline Scott <span class="age">(26)</span></p>
    <p class="matching">74% gemeinsame Interessen</p>
  </div>
</div>
```